# Angularjs - ng-disabled execution order on a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having an Angular directive with 'ng-disabled' on it. It seems that the "disabled" attribute is updated only after the linking phase of my directive. Can it be fixed?

See this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ruzudenura/4/) for an example.

When replacing the 'ng-disabled' with 'disabled="{{expression}}" it does work (but this will not work on old i.e browsers):
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/temuse/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at angular's code, the ngDisabled directive works that way: its link function registers a watch that changes the attribute.

So, angular will execute that link function (higer priority than your directive), then your link function, then do a digest which will change the "disabled" attribute. So it's no surprising that the attribute is not set when your link function is called.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L354

If you do your console.log calls inside a $timeout() call, it will display the right CSS properties, because the $timeout() executes on the next digest.

Comment: You got it write. Thanks!